# VLOOKUP Formula

Tags: excel, error-handling, formula, vlookup

I am normally god with VLOOKUP, however I am getting an error with my formula. In the cell with the N/A, I am trying to return the corresponding date to the number currently to the right of the N/A cell. I also want to copy this formula down to do the same with the rest of that 2-9 list. But, despite my efforts at the formula, I am still getting an error. Not sure why. Thanks!!

[image: my worksheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is not organized in a fashion for VLOOKUP to work the desired goal. If the number column was to the left of the date column it would work. Either switch the column order, or use `INDEX/MATCH`

```
=INDEX($CF$57:$CF$231,MATCH(CD64,$CG$57:$CG$231,0))
```